# Mono-Modul or Multi-Modul in Java Projects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, module, structure

A question regarding the structure of your J2EE/JavaSE projects:

I personally have always put class & web files etc. into one big module,
though I have seen several times that people split their project into modules with their individual compile output.

Obviously spliting your application into modules make it easier to package different levels of your app by only choosing the output of one
**but what else speaks for it and why shouldn't I have something like a mono-moduled app?**

E.g. open the firstcup project in the docs directory of your JavaEE installation. It's split into several modules that each have their own maven build file `pom.xml`

Answer (score 1):

If you make nice, logical splits:

- It's easy to swap a module out for another, i.e. switch an Oracle database module to a MySQL module
- You can have separate teams working on separate modules, and they don't necessarily need to know the inner workings of the other team's module
- Unit testing a small single module is much easier than unit testing one big module
- You can provide a custom module for each platform (I know, it's Java, it's supposed to be platform agnostic, but sometimes this is necessary)
- It's much easier to reuse code between unrelated projects if they're split up into modules - you might start a second project, which needs a database module, and think *'I have one of those already'*